# conan io : Unknown command 'export-pkg'

Tags: package-managers, conan

I am using conan io to create a package from pre build binaries. I found this post on the conan website: http://docs.conan.io/en/latest/creating_packages/existing_binaries.html but the problem is: Every time I try to use export-pkg command I get an error that this command is unknown. What is more I can neither create a --bare package. What is wrong? 
Do you have any idea what commands to use?

Thank you in advance,

K.

Answer (score 2):

So, it occured that I had a prehistoric version of conan. What was surprising because couple of minutes before I upgraded conan. What happened: the upgrade was not successfull (although eveyrthing looked fine) because I had installed pythonx86. As soon as I installed pythonx64 and re-upgraded conan I had access to these new commands,

just in case someone had similar issues....

Comment: It would be useful if you add the OS you are using, the version of python (2.7.X? 3.X?), what was the failure to upgrade (maybe it shouldn't fail to upgrade even in python 32 bits. I also think that the best is to report issues, questions in the issue tracker: https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues

Comment: Thanks, drodri! My OS is Windows 10. I will report that I cannot upgrade using python32 but. There was no error while installing. Operation was successfull on cmd line. But conan was not updated.